# How to call methods in random order(Java JDK11)?

Tags: java, pointers, methods, memory-address, java-11

```
class Scratch {

    public void meth1(){

    }
    public void meth2(){

    }
    public void meth3(){

    }
    public void meth4(){

    }
    public void meth5(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumber=(int)Math.random()*5;
    }
}
```

Here I have 5 methods, and I want to call them randomly. I am new to OOP but know a bit about C, in that case I would've stored the addresses of the functions(methods) in an array, generate a random number between [0,4] and call the functions using the array in random order. But in Java, I don't know how to get the memory address of a method. How should I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You do this with a "function-variable" of type [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) and its method [`Runnable#run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()).

```java
Scratch s = new Scratch();
List<Runnable> methods = new ArrayList<>();
methods.add(s::meth1); // this is how you reference a method itself
methods.add(s::meth2);
...
methods.get(1).run(); // this is how you "tell" the Runnable to execute its code
```

The abstract method `run` is overriden with the code you have, so this is a "reference" to call your method. In the package [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) you can find many classes that can be used in case your method has parameters or/and a return-value.

Now calling a random method from the list is pretty simple:

```java
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(methods.size());
methods.get(randomNumber).run();
```

Comment: Ditto. Misses the randomization part though. `int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(methods.size());
    methods.get(randomNumber).run();` From an attempt I made `    Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
    List<Runnable> runnableList = Arrays.asList(scratch::meth1, scratch::meth2,
            scratch::meth3, scratch::meth4, scratch::meth5);
    Collections.shuffle(runnableList);
    runnableList.iterator().next().run();`

Comment: For clarity each of the `Scratch` methods need to return a `Runnable` not a `void`

Comment: @locus2k No, the methods don't need to return ```Runnable```. This works as shown.

Comment: @akuzminykh. That is interesting. How come it can be fine as a void and not have to return a runnable since the list is marked as a runnable?

Comment: @locus2k The answer to that is in my answer. :-) Check out [Java Lambda Expressions](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to put your methods in a switch statement and get a random value that way:

```
class Scratch {

    public void meth1(){

    }
    public void meth2(){

    }
    public void meth3(){

    }
    public void meth4(){

    }
    public void meth5(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random r = new Random();
      Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
      int num = r.nextInt(5);
      switch(num) {
        case 0:
          scratch.meth1();
          break;
        case 1:
          scratch.meth2();
          break;
        case 2:
          scratch.meth3();
          break;
        case 3:
          scratch.meth4();
          break;
        case 4:
          scratch.meth5();
          break;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or with latest Java version something like `Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
        int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(5);
        switch (randomNumber) {
            case 0 -> scratch.meth1();
            case 1 -> scratch.meth2();
            case 2 -> scratch.meth3();
            case 3 -> scratch.meth4();
            case 4 -> scratch.meth5();
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }`

Comment: Interesting. Didn't realize you could do that with switch statements now.

Comment: They are called switch expessions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tedious, but you can set a certain range to a method. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rand=(int)Math.random()*5;

    if(rand < 0.1) {
        meth1();
    } else if(rand < 0.2) {
       meth2();
    } else if(rand < 0.3) {
       //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the `0.1`, `0.2` etc.